# Can the <object> element still be used in the embedding of SVG files?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can one go by CSS styling a svg if they need the benefit of browser caching?

I heard that you can embed a svg into HTML several ways, one way is by using the object element and if you want to apply styling to it, you'd have to link up the external style sheets inside the svg file. However, I cannot find any examples of this anywhere so I'm wondering if this is an outdated method or bad advice that  shouldn't be followed for whatever reason?

Comment: You can put CSS inside a <style> tag inside the SVG file.

Comment: Or ``fetch`` the SVG yourself and inject it into the DOM, add shadowDOM and you have scoped styling. Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about.

Answer (score 0):

The [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) element is still relevant and you can also use an external stylesheet in an SVG document. In SVG there is no `<link>` element like in HTML, so we can use the [@import at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) in the `<style>` element.

I have the following SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <style>
    @import url(externalstylesheet.css);
  </style>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
```

For the purpose of the example here on SO I replace the URL of the stylesheet with a data URI:

```
@import url('data:text/css,circle { fill: orange; }');
```

Now I can embed the SVG using the object element (also using a data URI for the SVG document itself):

```html
<object width="200" height="200" type="image/svg+xml"
  data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj4KICA8c3R5bGU+CiAgICBAaW1wb3J0IHVybCgnZGF0YTp0ZXh0L2NzcyxjaXJjbGUgeyBmaWxsOiBvcmFuZ2U7IH0nKTsKICA8L3N0eWxlPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjUwIiBjeT0iNTAiIHI9IjUwIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=">
</object>
```